# Report that updates yearly

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a report that is supposed to look at the number of baptisms at our church for the ministry year.  The Ministry year runs from Aug 1 - July 31. I currently have the report set to tell me the names of anyone that has a baptism date greater than 8/1/2016.  But I would need to change that year each year for it to report properly.   so I wanted to use a Case statement to have it update each year, but i am getting an error message with this: (The error is in the where clause, so I didn't include the entire report)

```
WHERE (P.organization_id = 1) AND 
((CandidateProcesses_BaptismDate68.datetime_value) between (
case
When datepart(month, getdate()) < 8 then ('8/1/'+ datepart(year, getdate()))
When datepart(month, getdate()) >7 then ('8/1/'+ 
datepart((year,getdate())-1))End) and Getdate())
```

Does anyone see why I am getting an error?
Thanks!

Comment: I tagged with SQL Server, because the code is clearly SQL Server.  If that is not the database you are using, then you have a SQL dialect issue.

Comment: What is the error message? Case statement in the 'WHERE' clause?!

Comment: Yes, it's SQL Server.

Comment: I added it in the WHERE clause because that is where I thought I needed to put the limitations on the query.  Writing SQL isn't my education background, I have been learning as I go.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error trying to add a string and a number.  You could fix that using `datename()` rather than `datepart()`.  But, I think this is a simpler approach:

```
WHERE (P.organization_id = 1) AND 
       year(dateadd(month, -7, CandidateProcesses_BaptismDate68.datetime_value)) = year(dateadd(month, -7, getdate()))
```

This subtract 7 months to get the "ministry year" and then compares that to the current date minus seven months.  That is, it subtracts 7 months and then normalizes on the calendar year.

This is a bit more expensive than your version, because it cannot use an index on `CandidateProcesses_BaptismDate68(datetime_value)`.  However, I doubt the database of baptisms is so large that the query will take very long anyway.  (If that is an issue, then your version can be made to work with some simple modifications.)

Comment: This seems to have worked!  This gives me the same results as when I have the hard coded date of between 8/1/2016 and getdate.  I guess I will know for sure if it's working as we would like it after 8/1/2017. :)